# SwiftUI state discarded when scrolling items in a list

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I'm very new to Swift and SwiftUI so apologies for the very basic question. I must be misunderstanding something about the SwiftUI lifecycle and it's interaction with @State.

I've have a list, and when you click on the row, it increments a counter. If I click on some row items to increment the counter, scroll down, and scroll back up again - the state is reset to 0 again. Can anyone point out where I'm going wrong? Many thanks.

```
struct TestView : View {
    @State private var listItems:[String] = (0..<50).map { String($0) }
    var body: some View {
        List(listItems, id: \.self) { listItem in
            TestViewRow(item: listItem)
        }
    }
}

struct TestViewRow: View {
    var item: String
    @State private var count = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Button(item, action: {
                self.count += 1
            })
            Text(String(self.count))
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's very similar to `UITableView`. *Cells* are reused. You are modifying the *cell* but you don't keep the value in the *model*. It would be pretty inefficient to hold 50 `TextViewRow` instances in memory. `@State`property wrappers make the property mutable and make its value persistent as long as the view is alive.

Comment: @vadian I was expecting the TextViewRow instances to go away, but the state to be preserved when they are 're-hydrated' ?

Comment: Imagine that it would have to preserve the value as well as the position in the `List`...

Comment: @vadian fair enough, thanks - is there any documentation on this behaviour? I couldn't find any mention of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Items in a `List` are *potentially* lazily-loaded, depending on the os (macOS vs iOS), length of the list, number of items on the screen, etc.

If a list item is loaded and then its state is changed, that state is not reassigned to the item if that item has been since unloaded/reloaded into the `List`.

Instead of storing `@State` on each `List` row, you could move the state to the parent view, which wouldn't be unloaded:

```
struct ContentView : View {
    @State private var listItems:[(item:String,count:Int)] = (0..<50).map { (item:String($0),count:0) }
    
    var body: some View {
        List(Array(listItems.enumerated()), id: \.0) { (index,item) in
            TestViewRow(item: item.item, count: $listItems[index].count)
        }
    }
}

struct TestViewRow: View {
    var item: String
    @Binding var count : Int
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Button(item, action: {
                count += 1
            })
            Text(String(count))
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```